# Am I eligible for a British Passport if my father was British, but I was born before my parents' married?

Tags: passport, nationality

My father is a British Citizen and holds a British passport and Australian passport. My mother is from the Philippines. 
I was born before they officially got married, however I am still able to hold my Australian passport and have citizenship for this country.

Currently I have an Australian and Philippine Passport.

I was born in the Philippines, but I reside in Hong Kong and go to school here.

Both my grandparents from my Father's side are British citizens, however they moved to Australia after deciding to leave the UK.

Comment: Where and when were you born?

Comment: Also, where was your father born?

Comment: British nationality depends on a lot of different circumstances. You should try to use the https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen site first to get an answer (which is usually good in case you were born after 1983)